# how can i working on a site without localhost?

Tags: wordpress, web

**Hello,**
Our site design is complete and open to visitors. Now we want to fix our site bugs, or add new features. And we want to upload the new version of the site whenever we are sure of the changes. The problem is that we can't use localhost because we're two people working on this project and we're far from each other. what is your suggestion? Can copying the original site on a subdomain (which is closed on search engines) be the solution? Sorry if my English is weak :)

Answer (score 0):

use GitHub or some "Team Code Engines" like Floobits...
You can use a FTP Server or some other File Transfer Protocol to share the Data but it's not "Live Coding" !

Answer (score 0):

I think **GitHub** is the best option. In Github you can handle version easily can create branch based on requirements.

but for that i think you need to buy premium account on Git, So that Your code will be private it will not be public.